# MySQL routine for porter or porter 2 stemming algorithm

Tags: mysql, nlp, porter-stemmer

I'm looking for a port of the Porter or Porter 2 stemming algorithm written as a MySQL routine (user defined function).  Has anybody seen one?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

http://forge.mysql.com/projects/project.php?id=215

OR

http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_stem/index.php

Should work.

Note: I haven't tried either of these myself.